# "typeerror: super expression must either be null or a function " in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using reactjs.
I try to make a login layout.
This is Login class:

```
import React, {Components} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import LoginButton from '../components/LoginButton';
export default class Login extends Components {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <LoginButton
                placeholder={"Login"}
                style={styles.LoginButton}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
..........
```

and this is LoginButton in components:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
export default class LoginButton extends React.Components{
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
}
    render() {
    const {placeholder} =  this.props
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={[this.props.style, styles.container]}>
            <Text style={styles.caption}
                placeholder = {placeholder}
            />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
}`........`
```

When I run this code, React Native giving error "typeerror: super expression must either be null or a function".
How do I fix it ?

Comment: I think you have a typo here `class LoginButton extends React.Components` and `class Login extends Components`. You are extending `Components` which should be `Component` like `class LoginButton extends React.Component` and `class Login extends Component`

Comment: Extends Component like React.Component. Because at Login class, I declared  {Components} from 'react'.

Comment: You should import `Component` only like `import React, {Component} from 'react';`

Comment: I've edited like you, but still not.

Comment: As it has been said, you should import `Component` instead of `Components`. If you did so, update your question accordingly.